# Проблема с ненужными символами

Tags: python, python-3.x

При выполнении этого кода:

```
data = dict()

with open('Names.txt' ,encoding='utf-8') as file:
    try:
        while True:
            key = next(file).rstrip()
            value = next(file).rstrip()
            data[key] = value
    except StopIteration:
        pass  


two_values = value.replace("'", "")
three_values = two_values.replace("р.","")
four_values = three_values.replace(" ", "")
next_values = four_values.splitlines()
print (next_values)
```

По идеи данные которые читаются из "Names.txt", изменяются (убирается апостроф, буква р, пробел и /n), однако при выполнении кода выводиться следующее:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В файле "Names.txt" хранится это:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В словаре "data" хранятся ключи и значения, где первый ключ это первая строчка и .txt а значение второе, второй ключ это третья строка а значение этого ключа четвертая строка. 
Как решить проблему преобразования текста (убрать апостроф, пробелы и буквы "р"). Спасибо.

Comment: В файле не такой апостроф, как вы удаляете. Скопируйте его из файла в строку в коде. Ну и добавьте замену р без точки на пустую строку.

Comment: @insolor Ничего не поменялось

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вместо кучи `replace` проще через регулярные выражения из строки удалять все нечисловые символы:

```
import re

text = "66'000р"
text2 = re.sub(r'[^\d]', '', text)

print(text2)
```